# setAssociatedAction() and setAssociatedScreen() not working

Tags: install4j

I'm developing some custom screens and custom actions and would like to create associations between them in much the same way that adding a "Create program group" screen suggests adding a "Create program group" action.

So I have a screen, and would like to associate an action with it. The action should be placed on the Installation screen. Within the screens bean info class, I've added the following line to the constructor:

```
setAssociatedAction(MyAction.class.getName(), InstallationScreen.class.getName());
```

This doesn't seem to do anything. I recompile, and re-add the screen to the installer, but it doesn't prompt me to add the action. I tried adding the same settings to the action's constructor, thinking that perhaps both need to create an association with each other to work:

```
setAssociatedScreen(MyScreen.class.getName());
setInstallerTargetScreen(InstallationScreen.class.getName());
```

It didn't help either. I even tried doing the reverse by creating the action to see if it requests that the screen be created as well, but no luck there. Luckily, setting the installer target screen worked as expected.

I've tried the following as well:

- Simple and canonical names for the class name.
- The bean info classes, just incase.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, if I am doing anything wrong. The documentation doesn't elude to any additional dependencies:

- [ScreenBeanInfo](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/api/com/install4j/api/beaninfo/ScreenBeanInfo.html)
- [ActionBeanInfo](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/api/com/install4j/api/beaninfo/ActionBeanInfo.html)

Hopefully this isn't a bug.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I was about to resolve this, but only as an extension to install4j. I used the wrong class when specifying the Bean class in the BeanInfo.

I had:

```
public MyActionBeanInfo() {
      super("Title", "Description", "Category", false, true, null, MyActionBeanInfo.class);
}
```

Instead of:

```
public MyActionBeanInfo() {
      super("Title", "Description", "Category", false, true, null, MyAction.class);
}
```

As a small enhancement, would it be possible to throw an exception, perhaps an IllegalArgumentException, from the super constructor if it is not a valid Bean class?

**BUT!**

I still received a ClassNotFound and NullPointer exception when not used as an extension.

Here's the stack trace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.geowareinc.util.installer.actions.MyAction
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.gui.views.installer.d.g.a(ejt:92)
    at com.install4j.gui.views.installer.i.b.a(ejt:41)
    at com.install4j.gui.views.installer.i.b.a(ejt:31)
    at com.install4j.gui.views.installer.i.b.a(ejt:18)
    at com.install4j.gui.views.installer.d.h.a(ejt:34)
    at com.install4j.gui.views.installer.d.h.call(ejt:32)
    at com.install4j.gui.views.installer.d.ax.a(ejt:1238)
    at com.install4j.gui.views.installer.d.g.a(ejt:32)
    at com.install4j.gui.views.installer.b.h.a(ejt:388)
    at com.install4j.gui.views.installer.d.ax.f(ejt:691)
    at com.install4j.gui.views.installer.d.bd.actionPerformed(ejt:540)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.checkPackageAccess(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.isPackageAccessible(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.gui.views.installer.d.g.b(ejt:60)
    at com.install4j.gui.views.installer.i.b.a(ejt:73)
    at com.install4j.gui.views.installer.i.b.a(ejt:53)
    at com.install4j.gui.views.installer.i.b.a(ejt:31)
    at com.install4j.gui.views.installer.i.b.a(ejt:18)
    at com.install4j.gui.views.installer.d.h.a(ejt:34)
    at com.install4j.gui.views.installer.d.h.call(ejt:32)
    at com.install4j.gui.views.installer.d.ax.a(ejt:1238)
    at com.install4j.gui.views.installer.d.g.a(ejt:32)
    at com.install4j.gui.views.installer.b.h.a(ejt:388)
    at com.install4j.gui.views.installer.d.ax.f(ejt:691)
    at com.install4j.gui.views.installer.d.bd.actionPerformed(ejt:540)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Your first call to setAssociatedAction in the screen bean info class is OK and should work. Please check $TEMP/install4j_error.log after adding the screen in your project and post the error here (if any).

Comment: I'm getting a ClassNotFoundException on MyAction as well as a NullPointerException when adding the screen. 

I also tried adding it as an extension, thinking maybe it needed to be one for this to work, but I get the following exception when I try to add the screen: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: MyScreenBeanInfo cannot be cast to com.install4j.api.beans.Bean.

Comment: It does not have to be an extension. Can you post the full exceptions?

Comment: I found the issue. My BeanInfo classes were specifying themselves as the Bean in their constructor, rather than the actual Bean. I'll add an appropriate answer, as well as a tiny feature request. I didn't know about the install4j_error.log file so that really helped, thanks!

Comment: Seemed to only fix part of it, see my revised post.

Comment: The exception comes from a simple Class.forName() call. Are you 100% sure that the class and its dependencies are added to Installer->Custom code & Resources?

Comment: The only two dependencies are the SQL Server and Oracle JDBC jars, which are both referenced in our extension jar's manifest under a lib directory. Is it possible that this is causing an issue? When I add the distribution to extensions folder, it maintains that structure, but adding it to the Custom Code & Resources screen doesn't (at least it appears it doesn't). The screens/actions that aren't working depend on those jars. Everything looks accurate otherwise.

Comment: Indeed, the manifest is not considered for Custom Code & Resources. Can you try adding all dependencies manually?

Comment: Right now I add all the dependencies directly, so each jar that I need is listed in that section. I tried adding "Scan Directory" for my lib directory as well to see if that might do it. The weird thing is that the install4j IDE can add both MyAction and MyScreen through the Custom Code context menu, but doesn't find them when looking for the associated action/screen, and only when it's not an extension.

Comment: Thank you, I have now reproduced and fixed the problem. If you want to get a pre-release build of 5.1.7 where this works, please contact support@ej-technologies.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in install4j. Associated screens and actions cannot be loaded if the bean is added on the Installer->Custom code & Resources tab.

This will be fixed in 5.1.7.